# Remove intermediate class when generating code from schema

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

Let's assume we defined a collection type in XSD as

```
<xs:complexType name="Foos">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

When generating Java code from it using XJC the type roughly translates to

```
public class Foos {
  public List<Foos.Foo> getFoos();

  public static class Foo {
    public String getBar();
    public String getBaz();
  }
}
```

As the collection type is part of some other type such as the root of the document, client code of the generated code looks somewhat like this

```
for(Foo foo : document.getFoos().getFoos())
{
  //do something
}
```

Is there any way to make the client code less ugly without writing a wrapper manually?

It should look like this

```
for(Foo foo : document.getFoos())
{
  //do something
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### UPDATE

There are XJC plug-ins that people have written to generate the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation instead of having the extra wrapper class.

- https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Alternative you could create the class with the `@XmlElementWrapper` yourself and have the generated classes reference it by doing the following:

**Document**

You could handcraft your own `Document` class to get the desired behaviour.  You can get the behaviour you are looking for by leveraging the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to get a grouping element.

```java
package forum18247182;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Document {

    private List<Foos.Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foos.Foo>();

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="foo")
    public List<Foos.Foo> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }

}
```

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

Here is an expanded XML schema based on your fragment that I will use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="document" type="Document"/>

    <xs:complexType name="Document">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foos" type="Foos"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Foos">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**Leverage Existing Class When Generating Java Model from XML Schema (binding.xml)**

We will use an external binding file to indicate that during class generation we wish to use our existing class for the complex type called `Document`.

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Document']">
            <jxb:class ref="forum18247182.Document"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

We will use the `-b` option to specify our binding file.  We will also use the `-p` option to force the package name of the generated classes to match that of our `Document` class.  We could also have made the package name of our `Document` class match the package name that results from generating classes from the XML schema.

```
xjc -b binding.xml -p forum18247182 schema.xsd
```

**Demo Code**

```java
package forum18247182;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import forum18247182.Foos.Foo;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("forum18247182");

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum18247182/input.xml");
        Document document = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Document.class).getValue();

        for(Foo foo : document.getFoos())
        {
          System.out.println(foo);
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
forum18247182.Foos$Foo@51f3336e
forum18247182.Foos$Foo@35b5a4ca
```

Comment: Amazing - many thanks. This has been driving me mad!